# Deep link for SonyLiv and Diseny + Hotstar Android apps using Intents

Tags: java, android, android-tv, android-deep-link

I am creating a recomendations app for android TV.

This will redirect users from my app to multiple streaming apps.

I have found most of the links but not able to find the APIs for "SonyLiv" and "Disney + Hotstar" application.

I am using "start activity intent" to launch the application.

How can I find the required API/URL links to these apps. These do not seem to have any documentation provided.

I tried to go through the Android Manifest file but did not get anything useful.

Comment: You can't really start 3rd party apps from your app without their package names, unless they have given a deep link as mentioned in your question, one hack for this is giving the user a intent chooser option where you ask ur app to open apps which offer video streaming feature OR get the playstore link for these apps and open their playstore page, let me know how it goes :)

Comment: @ZaidZakir sending to playstore wont work as i dont want to just open the app but also play the specific video in it. It worked for youtube very easily but other 3rd party apps is unknown. Also, getting the pachage name is not that difficult if i know it before hand and hard code it. I checked the manifest file of these apps and found some deep link consumers, but they do not seem to work.

Comment: Hi @SAnVidIDeas, did you got the solution? exactly am also looking. Please reply if found any solution. Thank you.